# Converting Julian Days in VB

Tags: vb.net, datetime, calendar, julian-date

I need to convert a set of Julian Days into proper Date Time format dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS

Problem seems to be that they are Julian Days FROM a certain date, im assuming the standard 1970? Below is my code:

Function:

```
    Public Function ConvertJulianDate(ByVal JulianDate As Double) As DateTime
    Dim julianRoot As DateTime


    julianRoot = "01/01/1970 00:00:00"

    ConvertJulianDate = julianRoot.AddDays(JulianDate)

    End Function
```

Call (I've hard coded a value in for now):

```
     Dim result As DateTime
     Dim JulianDate As Double
     JulianDate = 140.708368

     result = Utilities.ConvertJulianDate(JulianDate)
```

This gives me the value "5/21/1970 5:00:02 PM"

It seems the year is off as I know the data is from 2011. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Have you seen the [`Globalization.JulianCalendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3de6s8s) class?

Comment: @Tim I don't think we're talking about a Gregorian vs Julian **calendar** issue here; I think we're just using the typical usage of 'julian date' to mean 'count `n` days from base'

Comment: @sprocket if your data uses a value of `140.708368` to represent a date in 2011, then yes, it clearly doesn't use a 1970-based julian day. Your code is correct; you need to reinterpret the *data*

Comment: I agree with AakashM - I think your julianRoot value is incorrect. Can you post some known pairs of julian values/dates?

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't have any solid information/known pairs that I can use. The example above 'should' be somewhere in July 2011 however. 

Problem is I cant hard-code a value in, because data could be coming in at any time from any period before/after the hard coded value. (and hard coding is naughty!) As far as i can see, a value of 140.708368 etc is not enough to calculate a complete date without a known start year (if its not 1970...).

Answer (score 0):

After a heap of research into Julian Date formats, I realise I need to know the correct julianRoot - without an epoch relevant to the Julian Day, the value of the Year is useless.